# BigQuery SQL reshape four columns into one column with name of column as value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have a table that looks like:

```
id      code_44145  code_44146  code_44207  code_44208  
6580671    1             0          0           0
1639363    0             1          0           0
```

Is it possible to reshape my data into:

```
id          code    
6580671    44145
1639363    44146
```

Where the name of the column equal to `1` becomes the value of `code` in the new reshaped dataset. I have already presorted the dataset such that there will be no case where more than one column is equal to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, trim(col, 'code_') code 
from data
unpivot (code for col in (code_44145, code_44146, code_44207, code_44208))
where code !=0
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `case` expressions.  Assuming one `1` per row:

```
select id,
       (case when code_44145 = 1 then 44145
             when code_44146 = 1 then 44146 
             when code_44207 = 1 then 44207
             when code_44208 = 1 then 44208
        end) as code
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider yet another totally different approach - it does not even require explicit enlisting of columns

```
select id, trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)], 'code_') code
from data t, unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv
where split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] != 'id'
and split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] = '1'
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]